# How to perform custom mapping inside an IValueResolver using AutoMapper 9.0

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to create a custom `IValueResolver` that has nested mappings using the IoC AutoMapper style but am unable to inject an `IMapper` instance into the resolver.

Below is the original version of the resolver with the constructor still including the DI IMapper parameter.

Is there some way that I can use the nested `Mapper.Map()` calls within the resolver or is there another way that I can achieve the same result?

Not sure how much information is helpful here but I have multiple profiles that are added in the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` using `services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());`

Thanks!

```cs
public class PlannedTrainingExerciseDtosResolver : IValueResolver<TrainingPlan, TrainingPlanDto, ICollection<PlannedTrainingExerciseDto>>
{
    private Mapper Mapper { get; }

    public PlannedTrainingExerciseDtosResolver(IMapper mapper)
    {
        Mapper = mapper;
    }

    public ICollection<PlannedTrainingExerciseDto> Resolve(TrainingPlan source, TrainingPlanDto destination, ICollection<PlannedTrainingExerciseDto> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var plannedTrainingExercises = new List<PlannedTrainingExerciseDto>();

        foreach (var trainingPlanObjective in source.TrainingPlanObjectives)
        {
            if (trainingPlanObjective.PlannedTrainingExercises != null)
            {
                foreach (var exercise in trainingPlanObjective.PlannedTrainingExercises)
                {
                    var exerciseDto = Mapper.Map<PlannedTrainingExerciseDto>(exercise);
                    exerciseDto.Objective = Mapper.Map<ObjectiveDto>(trainingPlanObjective.Objective);
                    plannedTrainingExercises.Add(exerciseDto);
                }
            }
        }

        return plannedTrainingExercises;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is manual mapping. If you cannot rewrite it to really make use of AM, you'd be better of not using it at all. The resulting code would be clearer.

Comment: I'd definitely prefer to use AutoMapper if possible. I recognise there's not lots of contextual information here but is there anything you could suggest to point me towards a clean AutoMapper solution to resolve/redesign this?

Comment: The docs, the tests, there is a lot of info out there. You have to make better use of its capabilities. You can mix it with LINQ, but the end result should loot a lot better.